# Identifying positve and negative numbers by looking at it's binary form

Tags: binary, signed

New to the world of programming, I was reading one of the chapters in the beginning of **Java: The Complete Reference** which was Bitwise operators and the book explained how are negative numbers stored. It said, for example -42 is represented by inverting all the bits of 42 i.e. 00101010, yielding 11010101 then adding 1 to it finally resulting 11010110. It said due to the same reason there is no **-0** as it cannot be stored as it is 100000000 will exceed the capacity to be stored in the 1 byte.

The only thing that I cannot understand how would the computer understand whether it's a signed or unsigned number because though 11010101 is -42 but it can also be 213.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't say what number representation system is being used, it is not possible to say whether a bit pattern is negative or positive by looking at the bit patterns.  (Obviously!)

But if you are talking about two's complement binary integers AND you know which bit is the *most significant* one, then a positive number has the most significant bit 0.

For example:

- Assuming that 11010110 is a two's complement 8 bit number, and the leftmost bit is the most significant one, then that represents a negative number.
- But if 11010110 was actually the least significant 8 bits of the 16 bit number 0000000011010110, then *that* represents a positive number.

As you can see, it is important to know how many bits there are in the number representation scheme you are using!

---

> It said due to the same reason there is no -0 as it cannot be stored as it is 100000000.

Well ... sort of.   A better reason is that an N-bit two's complement representation has values from -2<sup>N-1</sup> to +2<sup>N-1</sup> - 1.  If you count them there are precisely 2<sup>N</sup> values in that range, leaving no room for a -0 value.

If you really want to understand this stuff about number representations properly, you need to also understand how two's complement relates to other ways of representing signed integers; see [Signed Number Representations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_number_representations).

It is worth noting that modern computer hardware uses 2's complement exclusively for integer representations.  Dealing with distinct -0 and +0 values makes things complicated for both hardware and software.

Comment: Thank you I get it now for the most part of it. Just ran through the article and have got some more clarity. I know this is might sound like a petty thing to a seasoned programmer like you but this concept was bugging for the past 3 days and then finally decided to ask on this forum.